# SQL Server : return results in one row with additional COUNT columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The table `dbo.AllApps` logs all executable that has been run, it has a column `ApplicationHash` which stores the exe hash value, a column `UserName` which stores the UserID which executed the exe.

If the exe has been run 10 times, there will be 10 entries in table with the same information but different timestamp and users that executed that instance.

I would like to produce a report that will only return 1 row of the 10 (with all columns time,name,desc ...) and additionally a column that will provide the count of the number of times the exe has been executed (total number of rows that is 10 in this example) and a count of the number of unique users that executed the exe (which is 3 in this example).

Any suggestions?

```
ApplicationHash TimeStamp UserName 
-----------------------------------
ABCDE12345      00:00:05  User1 
ABCDE12345      00:02:05  User2 
ABCDE12345      00:04:05  User1 
ABCDE12345      00:10:05  User3 
ABCDE12345      00:15:05  User3 
ABCDE12345      00:20:05  User1 
ABCDE12345      00:21:05  User2 
ABCDE12345      00:33:05  User2 
ABCDE12345      00:45:05  User1 
ABCDE12345      00:55:05  User1
```

Results should be somethine like this:

```
ApplicationHash ProcessCount UserCount
--------------------------------------
ABCDE12345           10           3
```

Here is what someone came up with which does solve the `ProcessCount` issue but I need a Unique UserName count as well:

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '20170401';
declare @EndDate datetime   = '20170406';

select top 1 with ties
    ProcessCount = count(*) over (partition by ApplicationHash)
  , ApplicationHash
  , ProcessStartTime
  , ApplicationType
  , Description
  , Publisher
  , ProductName
  , ProductVersion
  , EventDescription
  , CommandLine
  , FileName
from dbo.AllApps aa
where TokenType = 'Elevated' 
  and ApplicationType != 'com Class'
  and ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
  and ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
  and ProcessStartTime < @Enddate
  and ProductName = 'WizSvcUt Application'
order by row_number() over (partition by ApplicationHash order by ProcessStartTime desc)
```

Comment: Please shorten this essay.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `count(distinct userName)` to the temporary table. I've also changed your implicit join to an explicit join:

```
/* !!!!!DEFINE START AND END DATE FOR REPORT HERE!!!!!*/
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = 2017-01-01
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = 2017-01-02

/* Checks if the temp table #PCount exist and deletes the table if it does */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PCount') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #PCount
END

/* Performs a COUNT on the ApplicationHash entries and distinct user names*/
SELECT  ApplicationHash, 
        COUNT(ApplicationHash) AS ProcessCount, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT UserName) As UserCount
INTO #PCount
FROM dbo.AllApps 
WHERE TokenType = 'Elevated' 
  AND ApplicationType != 'COM Class'
  AND ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
  AND ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
  AND ProcessStartTime < @EndDAte
GROUP BY ApplicationHash

/* Pulls up the actual report and inserts the count value for the ApplicationHash */
SELECT 
    #PCount.ProcessCount, 
    dbo.AllApps.ApplicationHash, 
    dbo.AllApps.ProcessStartTime,
    dbo.AllApps.ApplicationType,
    dbo.AllApps.Description, 
    dbo.AllApps.Publisher, 
    dbo.AllApps.ProductName, 
    dbo.AllApps.ProductVersion, 
    dbo.AllApps.EventDescription, 
    dbo.AllApps.CommandLine, 
    dbo.AllApps.FileName
FROM 
    #PCount
INNER JOIN dbo.AllApps ON dbo.AllApps.ApplicationHash = #PCount.ApplicationHash
WHERE TokenType = 'Elevated'
AND ApplicationType != 'COM Class'
AND ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
AND ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
AND ProcessStartTime < @EndDate
ORDER BY 
    ProcessStartTime DESC
```

I'm not sure if this is supported in 2008 version, but in 2012 you could simply use the over clause for the count, and get the same result in a single query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationHash) AS ProcessCount,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationHash, UserName)  As UserCount
    ApplicationHash, 
    ProcessStartTime,
    ApplicationType,
    Description, 
    Publisher, 
    ProductName, 
    ProductVersion, 
    EventDescription, 
    CommandLine, 
    FileName
FROM dbo.AllApps
WHERE TokenType = 'Elevated'
AND ApplicationType != 'COM Class'
AND ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
AND ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
AND ProcessStartTime < @EndDate
ORDER BY 
    ProcessStartTime DESC
```

Comment: Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.

Comment: I see you've changed the code. However the results are having repeated values in ApplicationHash column

Comment: Did you try the first solution?

Comment: Yes i tried the 2012 solution. I get repeated values in ApplicationHash, it should only return the Unique Value of ApplicationHash. I also edited the code i gave in the question. I inserted a older code earlier.

Comment: But did you try the first one?

Comment: Yes first one works but it say if the processcount for a particular ApplicationHash is 10 then there will be 10 rows in the results. can we get this down to only 1 row?

Comment: not if you want all the rest of the data. If you only want the counts, you can use a much simpler query.

Comment: Could you post the one which you say is much simpler with just the counts?

Comment: That's the group by query. Just remove the `into #pcount` part.